# Call another aspx page in a different application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have 2 different system, lets say SystemA and SystemB.

In SystemB, there is page, say calculate.aspx, where it receive certain parameter and will perform some calculation. This page doesn't display and info, and only serves to execute the code behind.

Now i have a page in SystemA, lets say execute.aspx, that will need to call calculate.aspx in SystemB to run the desired calculation. I cannot use redirect, since that will redirect me to the calculation.aspx page on SystemB.

I had tried using HttpWebRequest but it doesn't call to the page. The code is as below:

```
HttpWebRequest myRequest =
                  (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(nUrl + '?' + fn);
myRequest.Method = "GET";

WebResponse response = myRequest.GetResponse();
```

Does anyone know what is the correct way of doing it? Thanks.

**EDIT**
Manage to get it done after changing my codes to above. Thank you all.

Comment: What do you mean `"it doesn't call to the page"`?

Comment: Besides that it is unclear what you mean by "it does not call to the page", you should maybe think about to design your "SystemB" to be a proper MVC4 application with a restful web service and then call that. It's clean, it's easy. It'll bring you forward on your journey to proper .NET web development.

Comment: it means the 2nd page, calculate.aspx, didn't receive any request although i had run the code above from execute.aspx

Comment: @Krumelur if that is possible, i would have done it, but this is an old system and we can't rewrite it..

Comment: Are you using IIS Express by any chance? If yes and SystemB is on another machine, it cannot be accessed from outside localhost. But you should see some error or response and if it's only a "400".

Comment: Place a break point and step through your code. Is `nUrl` correct? I'm going to assume that `fn` is a querystring param/value? Is this what you expect it to be? What is the response Status Code returned? The `newStream` should be wrapped in a `using` block as `Stream` implements `IDisposable`..

Comment: @Krumelur i'm trying it from a test server

Comment: I am probably missing something obvious here, but I'm puzzled by the whole part about the data and content which I'm not used to see in a GET Request.

Comment: @jbl you are correct. After modifying the codes i finally had managed to get it run successfully. Can i tag a comment as answer?

Comment: You should just write your own answer and then you can accept that.

Comment: No you can't mark a comment as answer :-) Done posting an answer. Feel free to post a more complete one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am probably missing something obvious here, but I'm puzzled by the whole part about the data and content which I'm not used to see in a GET Request.

You should, at your choice :

- convert your request to POST
- remove the part concerning the data

Comment: selecting this as answer as it obviously reminds me where the flaws is..thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a web service which would be the preferred way or use AJAX to send data to the page and get result in response.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
namespace SampleService   // this is service 
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetMessage()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
        public string GetAddress()
        {
            return "123 New Street, New York, NY 12345";
        }
    }
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  //  calling the service 
{
    using (ServiceClient<IService1> ServiceClient = 
           new ServiceClient<IService1>("BasicHttpBinding_IService1"))
    {
        this.Label1.Text = ServiceClient.Proxy.GetMessage();
        //once you have done the build inteli sense 
            //will automatically gets the new function
        this.Label2.Text = ServiceClient.Proxy.GetAddress();
    }
}
```

refer this link 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412363/How-to-Use-a-WCF-Service-without-Adding-a-Service

Answer (score 0):

You can create a WebMethod in your application then you call this WebMethod from any other application, you can return Json serializable  or XML data from this WebMethod